# How to implement First_Value() over() in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need an alternative for `first_value` in SQL Server 2008.

```
select distinct 
    spisznacka, 
    first_value(VdruhStavRizeni) over (partition by spisZnacka order by id desc) as stav 
from 
    isirshort
where 
    VdruhStavRizeni !=''
```

I need `spisznacka` and last not null value of `VdruhStavRizeni`... 1 `spisznacka` has 1 `VdruhstavRizeni`

Thanks for answers.

Comment: can you use another names for the variables? spisznacka and VdruhStavRizeni...........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `row_number()` and some more logic, like this.  I think you want:

```
select spisznacka, VdruhStavRizeni
from (select spisznacka, VdruhStavRizeni,
             row_number(VdruhStavRizeni) over (partition by spisZnacka order by id desc) as seqnum
      from isirshort
      where VdruhStavRizeni <> ''
     ) sv
where seqnum = 1;
```